# <GItOps> How to get git log to another repo?

Tags: argocd, gitops

I have a GitHub repo A which contains the code to deploy. And also have a gitbun repo B, which contains the chart. I made a GitHub Action in repo A, so when I commit, docker build my image and put it to ECR. Repo B is interlocked with ArgoCD, so its chart can be deployed to EKS Cluster.

When I build the image using docker, I set the corresponding git log as a tag. I want to put this tag in `values.yaml` in repo B so chart can be deployed automatically.

Comment: There are over a million ways to do this. Check the docs of your CI provider. Most of them provide a variable that holds the git commit and you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that with the GitOpsCLI: https://baloise.github.io/gitopscli/commands/deploy/

```yaml
# values.yaml
foo:
  bar: 123
  baz: xyz
```

```sh
docker run --rm -it baloise/gitopscli deploy \
  --username "IGNORED" \
  --password $GITHUB_API_KEY \
  --git-user "GitOps CLI" \
  --git-email "gitopscli@baloise.dev" \
  --organisation "repoorg" \
  --repository-name "reponame" \
  --file "values.yaml" \
  --values "{foo.bar: $YOUR_GIT_HASH, foo.baz: $YOUR_GIT_HASH}"
```